# How to get combo box selected value in button click event using C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box which has numbers. I have a button. I wants to get the selected value of combo box

I tried like below

```
Messagebox.show("Selected value =="+cbWeeksFrom.SelectedValue);
```

**Output**

```
Selected value ==
```

I am new to winforms.

**Update**

I tried

```
cbWeeksFrom.SelectedValue
cbWeeksFrom.Text
cbWeeksFrom.SelectedText
cbWeeksFrom.SelectedItem
```

it's not working. Not even bringing textbox value. I think it's not bringing any control values

Comment: What happens if you use `cbWeeksFrom.SelectedIndex`?

Answer (score 4):

use .Text property of Combobox to get selected value and use .selectedindex to find some value is selected or not

```
if (cbWeeksFrom.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show("Selected value == " + cbWeeksFrom.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please select a value");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is depend on how you added items to the combobox.

**SelectedValue** will work only in cases when `DataSource` was used

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
combobox.DataSource = numbers;

// on button click
MessageBox.Show($"Selected value is {combobox.SelectedValue}");
```

**SelectedItem** should work in any cases, except in situation where user input number(in editable part of combobox) which not exists in the `combobox.Items`

```
combobox.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

// user input "7" in combobox
combobox.SelectedItem // will return null
```

**SelectedText** is selected text in editable part of combobox.
Notice that if `combobox.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList` then `combobox.SelectedText` will always return empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Combobox.Text or Combobox.SelectedItem properties

Comment: Could you expand your question by providing other parts from your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
ComboBoxItem current = (ComboBoxItem)cbWeeksFrom.SelectedItem;  
string item =current.Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy solution :

```
  string selectedValue = cbWeeksFrom.Text;
  Messagebox.show("Selected value == " + selectedValue);
```